# using nginx, I want to re-write a URL with a .aspx extension

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am moving a .NET application over to a Rails application.

I need to re-write the url:

```
www.example.com/users/user.aspx?userid=1231
```

to

```
www.example.com/users/1231
```

How can I do this?

I don't want a redirect, I want it to seem like I am responding to this request "normally", but internally my Ruby on Rails application is going to think the URL was the 2nd url I posted.

Answer (score 2):

```
rewrite ^/users/user.aspx$ /users/$arg_userid?;
```

The trailing question mark prevents the query string from being appended to the rewritten URI.

Comment: Also `rewrite ^/users/user.aspx$ /users/$arg_userid? permanent;` worked for me.